# Python 3, easy_install, pip and pypi

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the current status of easy_install, pip and the repository (pypi.python.org) with regards to Python 3.x?

Are there versions of easy_install and/or pip that can install the right versions of packages from there? Else, are they expected soon?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

PyPi itself supports Python 3.  The [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/1.1.6#unix-based-systems-including-mac-os-x) package provides a version of easy_install that works with Python 3.

According to [the pip page](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip), pip support Python 3 since v 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

There is ongoing effort to provide support for Python 3 in pip.
See [Porting Pip to Python 3](http://groups.google.com/group/python-virtualenv/browse_thread/thread/9d0950c4b4c07a8e) thread on virtualenv mailing list or head directly to Vinay Sajip's [repo](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pip) on bitbucket.org

Answer (score 1):

As of version 1.0, [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) supports Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that easy_install is shipped with Python 3.4 and higher