# unable to use pip with Python 3.2 using distribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, easy-install, distribute

After installing python3.2 from src, I tried running:

```
curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
sudo python3.2 distribute_setup.py
sudo python3.2 -m easy_install pip
sudo python3.2 -m pip lxml
```

This gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/runpy.py", line 140, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, loader, code, fname = _get_module_details(mod_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/runpy.py", line 110, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/runpy.py", line 102, in _get_module_details
    loader = get_loader(mod_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/pkgutil.py", line 453, in get_loader
    return find_loader(fullname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/pkgutil.py", line 463, in find_loader
    for importer in iter_importers(fullname):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/pkgutil.py", line 419, in iter_importers
    __import__(pkg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pip-0.8.2-py3.2.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 56
    print dist
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Anyone able to get this working?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print dist` is invalid in Python3. It should be `print(dist)`.

However, with this error it is very likely that pip is **not compatible** with Python3. According to http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip it also does not support Python3.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ThiefMaster, my apologies for the dumb question.

Comment: Howdy. Your answer appears to be out of date. Pip now does support Python3.

Answer (score 2):

There is version of pip working with Python 3.
See my answer to [Python 3, easy_install, pip and pypi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849762/) question.