# "ez_setup.py" syntax error

Tags: python, easy-install

I am trying to install easy_install by running ez_setup.py from command line (64bit windows machine) and getting a "Invalid Syntax" on the following line:

```
except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e:
```

Python version 3.2.3

Any suggestions how to resolve this?
Thanks

**UPDATE:**
Sorry people, I am completely new to Python, now it is failing on this line:

> print "Setuptools version",version,"or greater has been installed."

Comment: Print is now a function, so it needs parentheses. Like  `print ("Setuptools version",version,"or greater has been installed.")`

Comment: Use [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/).

Comment: I also had to change 'import urllib2, shutil' to 'import urllib, shutil'. But now it fails on 'File "D:\Python32\lib\distutils\log.py", line 30, in _log if stream.errors == 'strict': AttributeError: errors' Is there a version of this script for Python 3? Or should I just install an older version of python?

Comment: As I said: use distribute. Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849762/python-3-easy-install-pip-and-pypi).

Comment: Distribute installation worked fine, now I just need to understand how to use it :/ Thanks! (Submit as answer so I could tag it?)

Comment: I will try an older version of python. Looks like python for windows is not really mature yet. Every time I try it it points me to broken python scripts and not working installs.

Answer (score 7):

Change the comma to 'as'

```
except pkg_resources.VersionConflict as e:
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get python 3.3 working on my x64 Windows 8 machine, and went through a couple of circles before finding the following method to load everything:

- Go to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
- Install distribute from binary - *ignore* the deprecation warning at the front of the installer.  Those unofficial binaries don't even have a "setuptools" download, and the projects don't seem to have been updated in years.
- Install pip from binary.  It didn't work for me in the first couple of attempts, something about pkg_resources, so I think distribute may have helped.

Now I have pip running and I can use it to install things.