# Python 3.2: How do you install easy_install

Tags: python, python-3.x, easy-install

So I'm trying get `easy_install` for Python 3.2.5. It seems like here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/ or here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.6c11 could be the place to go.

However, using `setuptools` I've replicated the following error: ["ez_setup.py" syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029284/ez-setup-py-syntax-error). After fixing it, and another error involving the `print` function, I receive yet more syntax errors. The person who asked the question is told to use `distribute` instead. However, the page for this says it's deprecated. I try it nonetheless using advice from this question: [Python 3, easy_install, pip and pypi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849762/python-3-easy-install-pip-and-pypi) however, more syntax errors.

Please can someone tell me how to install *easy* install?!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Distribute has indeed been deprecated by the new `setuptools` version 0.7.x series.

Install the latest [`setuptools` version 0.7.4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.7.4#id68):

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/0.7.4/ez_setup.py -O - | python3.2
```

As of the 0.7 release the Distribute project was merged back into the setuptools library:

> #### 0.7
>
> - Merged Setuptools and Distribute. See docs/merge.txt for details.

See the [indicated merge.txt document online](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/src/eb58c3fe7c0881cbb28de1c523f083ad8e7f427d/docs/merge.txt?at=default).